# Optimize a 4 table related oracle query

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, query-optimization

I need to optimize the following query but 'm not able to wonder how.

```
select distinct  v.codvia,
    v.codproine,
    v.codmunine,
    tv.SIMBOLO as SIMBOLO_TIPO_VIA,
    tv.NOMBRE as TIPO_VIA,
    c.nombrevia as NOMBRE_VIA,
    v.cp,
    m.nombre as NOMBRE_MUNICIPIO ,
    pr.nombre as NOMBRE_PROVINCIA   
    from tdinumvias v, tdimunicipio m, tdivia c, cditipovia tv, tdiprovincia pr
where (pr.codine = v.codproine) and  
          (m.codproine = v.codproine and m.codine = v.codmunine) and
      (c.codproine = v.codproine and c.codmunine = v.codmunine and
       c.codvia=v.codvia and tv.idtipovia=c.idtipovia)
```

there are indexes created for:
     v.codproine, 
     v.codvia, 
     v.codmunine, 
     c.codmunine, 
     pr.codine, 
     m.codine, 
     c.codproine, 
     v.idtipovia 
     and c.idtipovia

In it's correspondent tables but the performance is still really bad.

---

Added from comments :
Table sizes are
11M in tdinumvias, 
10K in tdimunicipio, 
970K in tdivia 
the others only have a few rows.

It takes a bit less than a second and i was wondering if it was possible to get it to 100 - 200 milis.

**Update:**

Finally we have created a new intermediate table with cp, codproine and codmunie precalculated and compiled as a view, then make the first query get data from this view, this gets the query  in about 300-400 Millis . it's not as good as we wanted but it's okay.

Thanks

Comment: What does your current `EXPLAIN PLAN` say for this query?

Comment: How many rows in each of these tables, and how long would you reasonably expect the query to take.

Comment: Gary i've got about 11M in tdinumvias, 10K in tdimunicipio, 970K in tdivia the others only have a few rows. It takes a bit less than a second and i was wondering if it was possible to get it to 100 - 200 milis.

Comment: Given that you need the CP value from tdinumvias, unless you can filter that 11M down to thousands of rows, you won't see that order of magnitude performance improvement. Some sort of materialized view may be appropriate if the tables aren't updated much.

Comment: @Fgblanch, do you really think that response time of less than a second from a 11M row dataset is "really bad"?

Comment: @Fgblanch, also, how big is your resultset? Do you really need that `DISTINCT`? What is the primary key on tdinumvias?

Comment: @Gary we give the cp in the "where" clause in order to filter the 11M.

@Mark Bannister a bit less than a second it's not a bad time but for the use we needed to low it down as much as possible.

Thanks all for your comments.

Comment: Given your latest update is this question still relevant?

Comment: @APC I guess not so much. I'm quite new in stackoverflow, what should i do now? close the question? delete it?

Answer (score 3):

I re-wrote using ANSI-92 syntax, which won't provide any performance benefit aside from readability:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.codvia,
       v.codproine,
       v.codmunine,
       tv.SIMBOLO as SIMBOLO_TIPO_VIA,
       tv.NOMBRE as TIPO_VIA,
       c.nombrevia as NOMBRE_VIA,
       v.cp,
       m.nombre as NOMBRE_MUNICIPIO ,
       pr.nombre as NOMBRE_PROVINCIA   
  FROM tdinumvias v
  JOIN tdimunicipio m ON m.codproine = v.codproine 
                     AND m.codine = v.codmunine
  JOIN tdivia c ON c.codproine = v.codproine 
               AND c.codmunine = v.codmunine
               AND c.codvia = v.codvia
  JOIN cditipovia tv ON tv.idtipovia = c.idtipovia
  JOIN tdiprovincia pr ON pr.codine = v.codproine
```

Review your JOINs - they are what is creating the need for the DISTINCT.  At least one JOIN needs to be converted into an IN or EXISTS clause to get rid of the duplicates.